# Ingesting CSV data into Hive using NiFi

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-nifi, avro, orc

i am trying to ingest csv data into Hive Database. for this purpose,

i tried with

```
listFile --> FetchFile --> ConvertCSVToAvro --> ConvertAvroToOrc --> PutHDFS
```

csv data is converted into ORC format and data is loading into HDFS. On top of this HDFS data, i can able to create hive external table.

now, i want to test with `putHiveQL` Processor.

for this, i need to convert CSV data to AVRO to JSON?

ORC data can't be loaded directly into Hive?

if yes, we have to create Hive table manually or it creates automatically?

Answer (score 3):

We can create **Hive table in NiFi** flow itself.

**ConvertAvroToOrc** processor adds `hive.ddl` attribute to the flowfles using that attribute we can create table in Hive using PutHiveQL processor.

```
listFile --> FetchFile --> ConvertCSVToAvro --> ConvertAvroToOrc --> PutHDFS -->
 ReplaceText(Always replace with ${hive.ddl}) --> PutHiveQL
```

Refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/191760/create-dynamic-partitions-based-on-flowfile-conten.html) i have explained in detail about the NiFi flow to create tables/partitions dynamically in hive.

- Once **ORC** data is loaded into `HDFS`, then create table on top of the HDFS directory.
- By using **`SelectHiveQL`** to read data from table and based
  on the `output format(csv,avro)` selected in processor results a
  flowfile in that format.